# Text burned into mac screen after leaving infinite print loop for 15 minutes! (Pico-8)

Tags: mac, display, lua, burn-in

I was at school, and I ran a program which would infinitely print a number, each time increasing it by .5. I wrote it in pico-8, a retro computer simulator, where you can write code in Lua. I left it for twenty minutes, and when I came back, there was a list of flashing .5 left in the screen, even after I quit pico-8 and restarted my computer! Please help! Is there any way I can remove it? Thanks

## Update:

For some reason, it seems to have just gone away by itself, but I'm going to leave this here for reference

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, leaving a special video on the monitor can fix burnt-in images on an LCD monitor. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=39HUG7QrQi8) is a YouTube video of one such video. Leave the video on for a couple hours and come back to see if the issue is resolved. Ensure the video is on full screen and that there are no black bars on the edges. Pick a different video that the beginning of the video references if you need a different resolution.

Also, ensuring that your monitor is correctly calibrated is also good! For Mac, [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19044?locale=en_US) is a link to an Apple article that can assist you with finding out how to calibrate your monitor. Below is a quote from the Apple article:

> Calibrate your display regularly to ensure accurate color.
>
> 1. Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, click Displays, then click
>      Color.
> 2. Click Calibrate.
>
> Display Calibrator Assistant walks you through calibrating your
>   display, then creates a calibrated color profile.
>
> For a more detailed calibration of your display, select the Expert
>   Mode checkbox, which is at the bottom of the introductory text in the
>   assistant.
>
> When the display profile is ready, it’s automatically assigned as your
>   display’s color profile.
>
> Some displays have additional built-in color accuracy and calibration
>   features. For more information, see the documentation that came with
>   your display.

Comment: For some reason, it seems to have just gone away by itself, but I'm going to leave this here for reference